# Dimension of orbit of a one-dimensional vector under action of $SO(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, general-linear-group

Intuitively, I know that if $e_1$ is a standard basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, than multiplying $e_1$ by elements of $SO(n)$ rotates $e_1$ around the $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere.

How do I prove, or at least mathematically motivate, this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you asking the action on ONE vector $e_1$ or a basis $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$?

Comment: Of one basis vector. (I know that the orbit is isomorphic to $S^{n-1}$, which is what I am trying to justify)

Comment: You have to show that: a) for any $U\in SO(n)$ we have $||Ue_1||=1$ (easy); and b) for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $||x||=1$ there is a $U\in SO(n)$ such that $Ue_1=x$ (slightly harder). The last condition means that the first column of $U$ should be $x$. Take the orthogonal complement of $x$ and apply Gram-Schmidt to construct the remaining columns.